# Using a UNION with SHOW CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the create code for multiple tables with the query:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_1
UNION
SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_2
```

they each work individually and share the same column names so I don't understand why it generates an error saying the syntax is wrong

if union wont work maybe there is another solutions like using a join (but i have no primary key) or making the `SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME` a subquery so the UNION won't throw an error

Comment: Union works only with `Select` Query

Comment: @AkhileshMishra well that explains it, any ideas for a workaround? currently my only solution is to seperate each query into different tables then merge them after, unfortunately this will be time consuming if I have a lot of tables

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two seperate queries you can use mysqldump with --no-data option

You can use below command to take schema using mysql dump

mysqldump --no-data -h localhost -u root -ppassword mydatabase table1 table2 > mydatabase_backup.sql

Comment: This won't work outside of SQL as mysqldump is a CLI command and it cannot be run as a sql script.